# Gitlab CI Pass Variable to Included Workflow

Tags: yaml, gitlab-ci

I have a worklow which uses a workflow from another project

```
include: 
  - project: {project repo}
    ref: {branch name}
    file: parent.gitlab-ci.yml
```

Is there a way to pass a variable to that, similar to how you would pass values to a Github Action? For Example...

```
include: 
  - project: {project repo}
    ref: {branch name}
    file: parent.gitlab-ci.yml
    Var1: Foo
    Var2: Bar
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a workflow is included, variables are essentially shared with the included workflow. See more [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#cicd-variable-precedence).

Answer (score 2):

Includes can now specify additional "inputs".

See
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/includes.html#define-input-parameters-with-specinputs

```
include:
  - local: 'custom_configuration.yml'
    inputs:
      website: "My website"
```

Where in the included file the input can be used by writing `$[[ input.website ]]` (in supported parts of the configuration)